# JavaFX 8 video playback freeze when running application from command line

Tags: java, video, javafx, javafx-8, mp4

when I run this JavaFX 8 application (video playback test) from Eclipse IDE, everything is fine. Application run video playback in loop indefinitely.
But when I run this application from command line:

```
java -jar test-javafx8-video-playback-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

it just playback for some seconds and then freeze the playback.
Here is a application source code:
[test-javafx8-video-playback](http://www.filedropper.com/test-javafx8-video-playback)

Please advise, thanks.

OK, here is a code snippet that plays video:

```
private void playBallMixingAnimation() {
    Media media = new Media(KenoKaironMain.getResourceURIFromProperties(KenoKaironMain.BALL_MIXER_URI_KEY));
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    mediaPlayer.setMute(true);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    animMediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
}
```

As I said, it works in indefinite loop in Eclipse, but not when I start application from command line.
Eclipse is using jdk1.8.0_51 and Windows/OSX is using jre1.8.0_51 and I have more than enough RAM for this small application.

Comment: please note: all information needed to solve your problem - including a SSCCE that demonstrations the issue - should be available in the question, not external (particularly not, if the externals require to download anything)

Comment: are you suggesting that I should add all code here in question?

Comment: just a SSCCE :-) Please google if you are not familiar with the acronym

Comment: how do you expect a code snippet to help if the problem is the different behaviour (working vs. not working) in a different context (IDE vs. commandline)? Voted to close, as it's not answerable as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found out.

It is all about supported media formats.
As you might know JavaFX supports this video formats:

1. FLV container with MP3 and VP6
2. MPEG-4 container with either AAC, H.264, or both

**Only FLV video file with On2's VP6 encoding will play in indefinitely loop both started from Eclipse IDE or from command line.**

MPEG-4 container with either AAC or H.264 will play in indefinitely loop only from Eclipse IDE and will freeze after first loop when started from command line.

This I tested using Oracle FLV sample: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv and confirmed by using this FLV sample: http://www.mediacollege.com/video-gallery/testclips/20051210-w50s.flv

For the MPEG-4 you can try by your self and make sure that it won't work in indefinitely loop from command line.

My test configuration is:
OS X 10.9.5, Java JDK 1.8.0_51, Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) and code snippet I posted above.

Comment: I dont get it... So JavaFX has H264 video and AAC audio decoders but it can only handle FLV container with VP6 video? What happens if the FLV has H264 video (like most modern FLV files)? Or else I suggest you also move on to learn other decoder libraries like **JCodec** or **FFmpeg** to expand video coding skills.